# why docker shows wrong ram usage

Tags: docker, rust

so i have a docker container and its ram usage grows over time like if its leaking memory.
first i thought its because my app is leaking memory but in local tests i saw nothing (app is written in rust with axum) then i checked the process itself and its ram usage is different than what docker says.

`docker stats` says container is using 50 mb but htop says something else
[image: htop]

Comment: Where do you see 50 MB in the output? The memory usage reported by `docker stats` should be approximately the sum of the RSS values of all processes inside the cgroup. (I believe caches/buffers are already subtracted in the `docker stats` output.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach image is from htop but 50 MB is in `MEM USAGE` section of `docker stats` and it grows by time

Comment: What's the output of `docker top <container name> u`? It should list all processes in the container and their RSS. The sum of the RSS values should be bigger than the memory usage reported by `docker stats` (due to shared memory).

Comment: @SvenMarnach docker top shows higher number. currently `docker stats` says my container is using 4.852 MB but `docker top` says its 4.548 MB

Comment: I don't know what else is included in the memory usage of a cgroup, but this still appears reasonably close. Maybe only caches are subtracted, and kernel buffers are included in the number reported by `docker stats`? Does `docker top` only show a single process for the container?

Comment: @SvenMarnach yes it only shows a single process for the container. i am trying different base images for my app now. first it was distroless then i changed it to alpine and now i want to try debian. it looks like they have diffrent memory usage growth. when it was distroless, ram usage growth was a lot higher than alpine. mybe its because of memry allocator?

Comment: It's rather surprising the base image has influence on memory consumption. The image doesn't really provide the operating system – the Docker container uses the OS (and thus the memory allocator) of the host system. The only thing in the image that influences Rust program executrion is the libc, which Rust by default links dynamically against. If you link statically against the libc, you don't really need any base image – just your binary will be enough.

Comment: Are you sure the increasing memory usage is a real problem that you need to solve?

Comment: @SvenMarnach so after a lot of search i found that my code allocates a lot of memory for its request handling but my problem is why the memory is not going back to os and it keeps allocating memory. i used `heaptrack` and it said there is no leak. so the problem is not with my code but its because of allocator. i have tried to change my code and it helped but still there is a ram usage grow over time like the memory is not going back to os.

Comment: If heaptrack says there is no leak, your program could still be inadvertantly holding on to memory it doesn't need anymore. This isn't really a "leak", since the memory is still reachable, but it has the same end result. Another possible cause is memory fragmentation. If your memory is too fragmented, it can't be reused efficiently.

Comment: @SvenMarnach why is it holding on to the memory? isn't rust supposed to drop things off after the end of its lifetime? i have stress tested my app with different works (auth, upload, db, etc) but only time it holds the memory is when i am saving data into a file. i don't know what is the problem.

Comment: I don't think glibc (which you are probably using) tries returning memory to the OS. However, memory that was freed will be resused for future allocations by the same process. If your memory becomes very fragmented, then this memory reuse will become less efficient.

Comment: Overall, there are far too many things I don't know about your project, so alas I don't think we will be able to get to the bottom of it in this comments section.

Comment: @SvenMarnach yeah i will open another question for it. thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you solved this? I'm having the same problem. My rust program uses 40 MB normally. Running in docker with the static distroless image, htop and `docker top` both say it uses 40 MB. But `docker stats` says it keeps increasing linearly forever. I have it deployed to nomad which keeps OOM killing it at its configured memory limit, 500 MB. It gets very close to them limit about 2 hours after starting, and then it happily hovers there for 0-12 hours without increasing any more, until, randomly, the OOM killer takes it out. I've also noticed sometimes it suddenly drops 100-200 MB out of nowhere

Comment: @DrewNutter Hi it turned out to be an issue with my allocator. i switched allocator to tikv-jemallocator and it got fixed

Comment: Interesting. For me it was related to a library creating a bunch of temporary files behind the scenes. I went down a rabbit hole and figured out why in general docker stats reports a different number. Turns out docker has a big flaw in how it tracks memory consumption, and it does not seem easy to fix. I was thinking about posting an answer to this question explaining the details but haven't gotten around to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely related to disk caches. docker stats command (unfortunately) does not substract all memory used by those caches.
(Deeper explanation here : https://medium.com/@bobzsj87/demist-the-memory-ghost-d6b7cf45dd2a)